# Creating a "Like" button with Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

Im trying to create a like button with Angular.js.
(It is just a heart icon. default color is white = NOT liked. It is red when liked. Like/unlike is toggled by a click)
I get some data from my web service that has also an array of some ID's. These ID's are the ones that clicked the like button before.

Then i populate the DOM with the ng-repeat directive according to the data retrieved from the web service.

I attach the button a ng-class that sets the proper class and a ng-click directive that is supposed to somehow change the class too.
* I cant connect between the ng-class and the ng-click result.

some code:

```
<div ng-repeat="photo in photos track by photo._id">
    <button ng-class="{carouselFooterButtonLikeActive : initLike(photo)}" ng-click="like(photo, this)">
        <i class="icon ion-heart"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
//  Handle like button click
$scope.like = function(photo, photoScope){

    HOW CAN I AFFECT THE NG-CLASS FROM HERE?
}


$scope.initLike = function(photo){
    if(photo.likes.indexOf($localstorage.getObject('userInfo').id) > -1) {
        $scope.liked = true;
        return true;
    }

    $scope.liked = false;
    return false;
}
```

Edit: added a possible data retrieved from the web service

```
{
    photos: [
      {
           src: "src1.jpg",
           likes:[111,222,333]
      },

      {
           src: "src2.jpg", 
           likes:[] 
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use as a flag some additional property that will be initially undefined on each `photo` element - say `photo.liked`. When user clicks it, `$scope.like` function sets this property to true. Then `ng-class` evaluates `photo.liked` to true and adds `carouselFooterButtonLikeActive` class to `button` element.

The code is as follows:

In the template:

```
<button ng-class="{'carouselFooterButtonLikeActive' : photo.liked}" ng-click="like(photo, this)">
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.like = function(photo, photoScope){
  photo.liked = true;
}
```

**UPD**
Say you have `photos` array:

```
[
{'src':'bla-bla.jpg', liked: true, id: 8347},
{'src':'foo-bar.jpg', id: 45},
{'src':'baz-baz.jpg', id: 47}
]
```

then only the first one will be shown with `button.carouselFooterButtonLikeActive` class, thanks to `ng-class` evaluation expression.

UPD2
If photo.likes is an array, you can use:

```
//template
ng-class="{'carouselFooterButtonLikeActive' : (photo.likes && photo.likes.length >0)}"

//controller
$scope.like = function(photo, photoScope){
  photo.likes.push(someUserID);
}
```

Comment: I was thinking to do the exact thing but this doesnt solve the problem as the like button has to be initialized first according to the data from the web service.

Comment: what do you mean 'button has to be initialized ' ? its a part of the template, iterating though photos array. when photos array is defined, you'll have data in shown in template

Comment: I mean that with your solution, all the buttons are set to an "Unlike status". What if i get from the service a button that has been "liked" ? your solution will show it as unliked instead of as liked.

Comment: then it still works - if one of the array items has liked = true, then it will be shown correctly as liked from the beginning. check updated answer

Comment: photo.liked is not defined until the user clicks the button. I think there is a misunderstanding.  Imagine you get data like this from the web service: {photos: [ {src: "src1.jpg, likes:[111,222,333]},{src: "src2.jpg, likes:[] }]}. As you can see, the first element has 3 likes and the second has none. When i load my template i would like to show that.  And also add a like toggle with ng-click

Comment: Thank you for trying but this is not answering the question. Still cant handle the buttons initialization with ng-repeat